# Remove element from 3 dimension JSON with php

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

This is my JSON:

```
{
   "status":"ok",
   "status_message":"Query was successful",
   "data":{
      "movie_count":3,
      "limit":20,
      "page_number":1,
      "movies":[
         {
            "id":5039,
            "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/movie\/steve-jobs-2015",
            "imdb_code":"tt2080374",
            "title":"Steve Jobs",
            "title_english":"Steve Jobs",
            "title_long":"Steve Jobs (2015)",
            "slug":"steve-jobs-2015",
            "year":2015,
            "rating":7.3,
            "runtime":122,
            "genres":[
               "Biography",
               "Drama"
            ],
            "summary":"His passion and ingenuity have been the driving force behind the digital age. However his drive to revolutionize technology was sacrificial. Ultimately it affected his family life and possibly his health. In this revealing film we explore the trials and triumphs of a modern day genius, the late CEO of Apple inc. Steven Paul Jobs.",
            "description_full":"His passion and ingenuity have been the driving force behind the digital age. However his drive to revolutionize technology was sacrificial. Ultimately it affected his family life and possibly his health. In this revealing film we explore the trials and triumphs of a modern day genius, the late CEO of Apple inc. Steven Paul Jobs.",
            "synopsis":"His passion and ingenuity have been the driving force behind the digital age. However his drive to revolutionize technology was sacrificial. Ultimately it affected his family life and possibly his health. In this revealing film we explore the trials and triumphs of a modern day genius, the late CEO of Apple inc. Steven Paul Jobs.",
            "yt_trailer_code":"aEr6K1bwIVs",
            "language":"English",
            "mpa_rating":"R",
            "background_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_2015\/background.jpg",
            "background_image_original":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_2015\/background.jpg",
            "small_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_2015\/small-cover.jpg",
            "medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_2015\/medium-cover.jpg",
            "large_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_2015\/large-cover.jpg",
            "state":"ok",
            "torrents":[
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/torrent\/download\/88208992C5CA27CAF4F9AC2B8F2908F548D8082A.torrent",
                  "hash":"88208992C5CA27CAF4F9AC2B8F2908F548D8082A",
                  "quality":"720p",
                  "seeds":247,
                  "peers":31,
                  "size":"904.98 MB",
                  "size_bytes":948940308,
                  "date_uploaded":"2016-02-03 19:22:46",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1454545366
               },
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/torrent\/download\/46E7E399850BDC9039182074EFA32957CD82C9F1.torrent",
                  "hash":"46E7E399850BDC9039182074EFA32957CD82C9F1",
                  "quality":"1080p",
                  "seeds":273,
                  "peers":35,
                  "size":"1.87 GB",
                  "size_bytes":2007897211,
                  "date_uploaded":"2016-02-03 23:05:02",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1454558702
               }
            ],
            "date_uploaded":"2016-02-03 19:22:46",
            "date_uploaded_unix":1454545366
         },
         {
            "id":4731,
            "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/movie\/steve-jobs-the-man-in-the-machine-2015",
            "imdb_code":"tt4425064",
            "title":"Steve Jobs: The Man in the Machine",
            "title_english":"Steve Jobs: The Man in the Machine",
            "title_long":"Steve Jobs: The Man in the Machine (2015)",
            "slug":"steve-jobs-the-man-in-the-machine-2015",
            "year":2015,
            "rating":6.8,
            "runtime":128,
            "genres":[
               "Documentary"
            ],
            "summary":"In his signature black turtleneck and blue jeans, shrouded in shadows below a milky apple, Steve Jobs' image was ubiquitous. But who was the man on the stage? What accounted for the grief of so many across the world when he died? From Oscar-winning director Alex Gibney, 'Steve Jobs: The Man In The Machine' is a critical examination of Jobs who was at once revered as an iconoclastic genius and a barbed-tongued tyrant. A candid look at Jobs' legacy featuring interviews with a handful of those close to him at different stages in his life, the film is evocative and nuanced in capturing the essence of the Apple legend and his values which shape the culture of Silicon Valley to this day.",
            "description_full":"In his signature black turtleneck and blue jeans, shrouded in shadows below a milky apple, Steve Jobs' image was ubiquitous. But who was the man on the stage? What accounted for the grief of so many across the world when he died? From Oscar-winning director Alex Gibney, 'Steve Jobs: The Man In The Machine' is a critical examination of Jobs who was at once revered as an iconoclastic genius and a barbed-tongued tyrant. A candid look at Jobs' legacy featuring interviews with a handful of those close to him at different stages in his life, the film is evocative and nuanced in capturing the essence of the Apple legend and his values which shape the culture of Silicon Valley to this day.",
            "synopsis":"In his signature black turtleneck and blue jeans, shrouded in shadows below a milky apple, Steve Jobs' image was ubiquitous. But who was the man on the stage? What accounted for the grief of so many across the world when he died? From Oscar-winning director Alex Gibney, 'Steve Jobs: The Man In The Machine' is a critical examination of Jobs who was at once revered as an iconoclastic genius and a barbed-tongued tyrant. A candid look at Jobs' legacy featuring interviews with a handful of those close to him at different stages in his life, the film is evocative and nuanced in capturing the essence of the Apple legend and his values which shape the culture of Silicon Valley to this day.",
            "yt_trailer_code":"SrlPyKxdMX4",
            "language":"English",
            "mpa_rating":"R",
            "background_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_the_man_in_the_machine_2015\/background.jpg",
            "background_image_original":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_the_man_in_the_machine_2015\/background.jpg",
            "small_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_the_man_in_the_machine_2015\/small-cover.jpg",
            "medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_the_man_in_the_machine_2015\/medium-cover.jpg",
            "large_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/steve_jobs_the_man_in_the_machine_2015\/large-cover.jpg",
            "state":"ok",
            "torrents":[
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/torrent\/download\/C04D9D0C73281EE708C5A7DD44366B77C54CD722.torrent",
                  "hash":"C04D9D0C73281EE708C5A7DD44366B77C54CD722",
                  "quality":"720p",
                  "seeds":23,
                  "peers":4,
                  "size":"692.27 MB",
                  "size_bytes":725897708,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-11-20 16:19:01",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1448054341
               },
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/torrent\/download\/4B373BB0E4AFEA0467E87EED686D9A2458D41CC3.torrent",
                  "hash":"4B373BB0E4AFEA0467E87EED686D9A2458D41CC3",
                  "quality":"1080p",
                  "seeds":17,
                  "peers":2,
                  "size":"1.31 GB",
                  "size_bytes":1406601789,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-11-20 16:19:08",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1448054348
               }
            ],
            "date_uploaded":"2015-11-20 16:19:01",
            "date_uploaded_unix":1448054341
         },
         {
            "id":1699,
            "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/movie\/jobs-2013",
            "imdb_code":"tt2357129",
            "title":"Jobs",
            "title_english":"Jobs",
            "title_long":"Jobs (2013)",
            "slug":"jobs-2013",
            "year":2013,
            "rating":5.9,
            "runtime":128,
            "genres":[
               "Biography",
               "Drama"
            ],
            "summary":"The story of Steve Jobs' ascension from college dropout into one of the most revered creative entrepreneurs of the 20th century.",
            "description_full":"The story of Steve Jobs' ascension from college dropout into one of the most revered creative entrepreneurs of the 20th century.",
            "synopsis":"The story of Steve Jobs' ascension from college dropout into one of the most revered creative entrepreneurs of the 20th century.",
            "yt_trailer_code":"FrvkCS0ZGPU",
            "language":"English",
            "mpa_rating":"PG-13",
            "background_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/JOBS_2013\/background.jpg",
            "background_image_original":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/JOBS_2013\/background.jpg",
            "small_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/JOBS_2013\/small-cover.jpg",
            "medium_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/JOBS_2013\/medium-cover.jpg",
            "large_cover_image":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/assets\/images\/movies\/JOBS_2013\/large-cover.jpg",
            "state":"ok",
            "torrents":[
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/torrent\/download\/7BB7D4B9AF75FCA9385C02B2A031950C5F05F36F.torrent",
                  "hash":"7BB7D4B9AF75FCA9385C02B2A031950C5F05F36F",
                  "quality":"720p",
                  "seeds":63,
                  "peers":6,
                  "size":"921.77 MB",
                  "size_bytes":966545900,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-11-01 00:25:49",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1446351949
               },
               {
                  "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/torrent\/download\/1E82235C55769328435AD1AC69D05D1E5D741B9C.torrent",
                  "hash":"1E82235C55769328435AD1AC69D05D1E5D741B9C",
                  "quality":"1080p",
                  "seeds":29,
                  "peers":8,
                  "size":"1.95 GB",
                  "size_bytes":2093796557,
                  "date_uploaded":"2015-11-01 00:25:52",
                  "date_uploaded_unix":1446351952
               }
            ],
            "date_uploaded":"2015-11-01 00:25:49",
            "date_uploaded_unix":1446351949
         }
      ]
   },
   "@meta":{
      "server_time":1461011131,
      "server_timezone":"EST5EDT",
      "api_version":2,
      "execution_time":"0.01 ms"
   }
}
```

What I need to do is remove from the "Torrents" item, every item that has "quality=720p".

I have tried something like this:

```
    $data= json_decode($a, true);
    //Loop through the array contained in the 'torrents' object.
    foreach ($data['data']['movies'] AS $key => $value) {
       // Assess the value of the 'quality' object
            foreach ($value['torrents'] AS $key2 => $value2) {
               if ($value2['quality'] == "720p"){
                    echo $value2['quality'];
                    unset($value['torrents'][$key2]);
               }
            }
    }
    $data= json_encode($data);
    echo $data;
```

but since this JSON has more than 2 dimensions, I dont know how to make this work.

How can I do this?

Regards,

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW: there's no `json script` thing. It's just JSON.

Comment: The word "filter" doesn't tell us anything about what you are trying to do.

Comment: This? http://underscorejs.org/#where

Comment: So you are asking this site how you can pirate movies of a better quality?

Comment: No, Im asking this site how to remove items from JSON with PHP.

Comment: Use $for['bar'] for arrays $foo->bar for object. Torrent is an object of movies I.e $value2->quality

Answer (score 0):

The part of your array containing the 720p is actually an object as defined by {} whereas an array is []. What should work is:

```
$data= json_decode($json, true); 
//Loop through the array contained in the 'torrents' object.
foreach ($data->torrents AS $value) {
   // Assess the value of the 'quality' object
   if ($value->quality == "720p"){
    unset($value->quality);
   }
}
```

P.s, in future can I suggest you simplify your example data, and format it correctly for readability.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I tried your example but it didn't work. Im getting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". B the way, sorry about that, I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: Could you please accept my edit suggestion. On my mobile so impossible to read the Json as is.

Comment: Done, didn't know that you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: Aha, deeper array than I had noticed. You need to loop $data->movies first then inside that loop, loop through torrents.

Comment: I was able to do that before (deleted my code) but I wasnt able to unset that spesific element, and then encode the new JSON.

Comment: I have updated my PHP code in the example. With that code I can get to the quality values and print them, but I cant unset it.